# Android prob to show pdf in webview

Tags: android, pdf, webview, google-docs

I am using android `Webview` to load a url to show a pdf file.
Here is my code:

```
public class TestProgectActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        WebView mtWebView=new WebView(this);
        setContentView(mtWebView);

        mtWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        mtWebView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.cbwe.gov.in/HTMLEditor1/pdf/sample.pdf");            

    }
}
```

It is working for the link "https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.cbwe.gov.in/HTMLEditor1/pdf/sample.pdf".

But it is not working for "https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.pancreaze.net/pdf/PANCREAZE.pdf". When I am firing this url through `Webview` it is showing HTML content in the WebView instead of the actual pdf file. Here is the screenshot.

[image]

What is problem in my code?

Comment: try this `http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://www.abc.com/xxxxxyyyyyxz.pdf`

Comment: No change changing the URL as you stated.